# Switching tasks for a given thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to build a scheduler using red-black tree.
The tree would have all the runnable tasks which are ready to be executed. I am planning to write my own schedule function which assigns one of the tasks in the tree to one of the four working threads. Every thread would visit scheduler periodically to see if it has to continue the same task or switch to new task.
Now, how can I make a thread to halt a particular task and assign it a new task.
The halted task goes back to the tree and waits for some other thread to continue its execution.

For, simplicity lets assume that I don't have any variables/ data to store from the task that gets halted.

All the resources I had seen till either uses a java executor service or just assigns a single task to threads. So, I need some help here...

Comment: Simple: no way. Closest you can get is a specific task interface that does just a bit of work per method call. When the method returns, you can do your checking.

Comment: When you say: *"Every thread would visit scheduler periodically to see if it has to continue the same task or switch to new task"*, that implies that the code of the tasks themselves will call some sort of `yield` function themselves periodically to allow themselves to be swapped out.  If that's the case, this becomes a more workable problem.

Comment: Or can each task be it's own thread and allow the scheduler (running on it's own thread) to just calls `suspend` and `resume` on each task thread to insure only 4 are running at any given moment?   `suspend` and `resume` are deprecated in Java, but if this is for an academic exercise, they could be useful for a simple design.

Comment: To clarify, say I have 4 threads, but I might have 24 tasks to execute. All the tasks should be fairly executed by these 4 working threads. Hence, I thought there could be a way to switch tasks for a given thread.

Comment: By now you should know that there is preemptive and collaborative multitasking, and that preemptive requires assistance from the CPU. Your operating system is already using the CPU so your scheduler could only use collaborative multitasking...

Comment: Keet - the most likely way you would do this, from an academic exercise, is that each task would be its own thread.  And the schedule would wake up every few milliseconds to suspend/resume a set of task threads to insure only 4 are running.  (This is essentially emulating what preemtive scheduling does in the operating system).    Otherwise, each "task" will be expected to do it's own yielding back to the scheduler.  Which design did your professor instruct you towards?

Comment: Selbie, thanks for suggestions.. It's mostly towards the second approach. The end scheduler should mimic the CFS scheduler with threads assuring fairness to all the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write your "tasks" to do a chunk of work, and `return` in such a way that they can be called many times, each time picking up where it left off last time.

I know you are asking for something to interrupt the task proactively, but that is nonsense because the running program will have an active stack.  There is no way to reassign that stack to another thread.  The thread *is* the stack so to speak.

So the only way to accomplish this in Java is to write tasks that return, effectively popping the stack back to the start position every time.  Only in that case you could have a pool of thread that pick these re-entrant tasks from queue, and call them interchangeably.

Answer (score -1):

Use quartz for this, you don't need remake round, the quarts do all that for you, only use.

Comment: As this is part of my project, unfortunately, I cannot use quartz. I have to build the scheduler on my own.

Comment: hum.. i understand, this is a big Job, if you need an architect, call me.
this is a had job.